# Finding the bottleneck for asyncio tasks slowing down overall

Tags: python, python-asyncio, paramiko, yappi

For python asyncio, what are good tools do debug performance bottlenecks? I have a quart webserver that is the frontend for a backend that holds SSH connections (via `paramiko`) to multiple devices (about 30 or 40). What I notice is that, once all those connections are up and running, the web frontend seems to be slowing down a lot. Requests take a long time to complete and I am seeing tons of warnings in the console where asyncio warns about slow tasks.

The problem is, a lot of the methods that asyncio warns about don't really have anything that is blocking the main thread anymore. I have tried `yappi` to search for slowness on the main thread but it doesn't help much.

I am starting to wonder if this is either a general runloop starvation and I simply have too many tasks, or if there are some other resources that get constraint here that could cause this.

My problem is a lack of debugging tools. I would love to see a graphical representation of which method takes how long and what it's waiting for.

Comment: I don't think we can help without seeing your code (because there are all sorts of things that can cause performance issues). For example, I don't believe that Paramiko has asyncio support, so I guess I am surprised that things are working *at all*.

Comment: To add to what @larsks answer, I think the alternative library for this use case is [asyncssh](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which support open asynchronous ssh connection.